# digital pH indicator

Tags: ph

Those who work in industries will understand this question better. A pH electrode has pH vs mV table will be somewhat similar to this image. Our company has a digital pH indicator showing input as -1500mV to 1500mV. why this large range of volts, when i/p from electrode can be vary from may be around -500mV to 500mV.

Answer (score 1):

Either for high temperature/pressure pH probes or for ORP measurement.